# excel macro find the row

Tags: vba, excel

I need to find a row that contains a specific word etc. AND after a certain (variable) row number.

The latest row number formula is as follows:

```
Son1 = Range(KirilimKolonu & ":" & KirilimKolonu) _
           .Find(what:="1", _
                 after:=Range(KirilimKolonu & "1"), _
                 searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

something like

```
x =1

do while x < 785

if range(KirilimKolonu & x).value = 1 then exit loop else

x = x + 1

Loop
```

there must be a better way instead of a loop...

Comment: It sounds like you just want to do another `.Find` with the `after` option set to the row `Son1 + 1`?

Comment: @arcadeprecinct i want to find the latest row with an option for example which is before than row 785... (row number changes for each condition)

Comment: Do you want to find the last row before a certain row or the first row after a  certain row? Your question and comment contradict each other. Can you describe in more detail what you want to find? Maybe with a small example. (Edit it into your question)

Comment: @arcadeprecinct  i want to find the last row before a certain row which contains a certain value.

Comment: So you just need to modify the `After` option in your example..? `After` doesn't mean that it searches only cells after that, it's just the starting cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to modify the range to search and search backwards. If you specify the cell to start the search (the `After` option) somewhere in the middle, the search will wrap around and your hit might actually be after the starting cell (rather than no hit at all)

```
Dim foundCell As Range
Dim searchRange As Range
Dim Son1 As Long

Set searchRange = Range("A1:A" & 785) 'your variable goes here

Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(what:="1", searchdirection:=xlPrevious) 'specify other options if you must

'you need to check if something was found or .Row will cause an error.
If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
    Son1 = foundCell.Row
Else
    'do what you need to if there is no match
End If
```

[More options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx)

Comment: thanks for your help. i used xlNext starting from the beginning... 
``

Comment: `

Set searchRange = Range(KirilimKolonu & SubB3 & ":" & KirilimKolonu & SubB4)

Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(what:="4", searchdirection:=xlNext)

If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
    Son4 = foundCell.Row
    
    If Son5 > SubB5 Then
    
    Range(Kolon2 & SubB5).Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9," & Kolon2 & SubB5 + 1 & ":" & Kolon2 & Son5 & ")"
        
    Else
    
    Range(Kolon2 & SubB5).Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9," & Kolon2 & SubB5 + 1 & ":" & Kolon2 & LastRow & ")"
    
    End If
    
End If
`

Comment: posting longer portions of code is never a good idea. Do you have another issue? Did my code help you? If not why not?

Comment: yes, it helped and i wanted to put the last version , maybe it may help others... Thanks a lot !